# Can foreach loops in Azure Logic Apps perform multiple actions per iteration?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to do this ***without*** the foreach action being a child workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at this stage I don't think Logic Apps supports any of the loop structure (for each, do until) to be applied to more than one action. There is a blog post from Sandro Pereira where he researches this:

https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/logic-apps-how-to-add-several-actions-inside-a-loop-or-foreach-actions/

The exception for this is Split-On that works similar to debatching on BizTalk (loading several workflows for each elements inside an "envelope" message).

I hope this helps, Wagner

Answer (score 1):

I found a YouTube video from the Logic App team where they described a way to do this that would work for my current scenario using splitOn on a trigger:

https://youtu.be/ce9qg_6s2iI?t=5m30s

This does not, however, solve a situation where you want to perform multiple actions for an item in a collection where the collection is obtained outside of the trigger.  It sounds like there was a some sort of a repeat capability with a repeatItem() function, but this may have been removed in favor of either splitOn or foreach.  foreach only works over one action as well (as far as I can tell).

Comment: FYI: foreach is just repeat renamed.